# Few questions encountered when trying to implementing a state machine in TLA+

Tags: tla+

I'm trying to implement a state machine in TLA+, and I encountered a few questions when checking it with TLC.

I think there might be some problems in my spec,and you might not understand what I'm implementing in spec.So I want to explain what I'm doing first.

First,it will read two inputs.In_sentence_seq stand for future command sequence,changing the state of the state machine.In_layer_name stand for input data,and will be used in some specfic states later.And they will turn into variable in_seq and layer_set,maybe after some processes though.

Then,the state machine starts with Init,and then change its state(cur_state) by state_changer when in_seq not empty, or by state_stabler when in_seq empty.After that, do something(meaning only one in actions derived_def_global,rule_head,derived_def_rule,check_statement) depend on cur_state or do nothing if cur_state equals 0.After that,change state by state_changer or state_stabler again.And the state machine will repeat the change state->do something or nothing process again and again.

My spec is written in this way:

```
----------------------------- MODULE Parser -----------------------------
EXTENDS Integers,Naturals,Reals,Sequences

CONSTANTS in_sentence_seq,in_layer_names

ASSUME  /\ in_sentence_seq \in Seq(1..5)
        /\ in_layer_names \subseteq 0..10

VARIABLES in_seq,layer_set,cur_state,cur_scope,rule_nums,layer_connection_set

vars == << in_seq,layer_set,cur_state,cur_scope,rule_nums,layer_connection_set >>

layer_range == {{x,y}:x \in 0..10,y \in -1..10}

layer_connection_range == {<<x,y,z>>: x \in layer_range , y \in layer_range , z \in layer_range}

TypeOK ==     /\ in_seq \in Seq(1..5)
              /\ layer_set \subseteq layer_range
              /\ cur_state \in 0..5
              /\ cur_scope \in -1..10
              /\ rule_nums \in 0..10
              /\ layer_connection_set \subseteq layer_connection_range
                 
Init == /\ in_seq = in_sentence_seq
        /\ layer_set = {{x,y}:x \in in_layer_names,y \in {-1}}
        /\ cur_state = 0
        /\ cur_scope = -1
        /\ rule_nums = 0
        /\ layer_connection_set =  {}
        
           
state_changer == /\ Len(in_seq) >= 1 
                 /\ cur_state' = Head(in_seq)
                 /\ in_seq' = Tail(in_seq)
                 /\ UNCHANGED << layer_set,cur_scope,rule_nums,layer_connection_set >>  
                 
                      

state_stabler == /\ Len(in_seq) = 0
                 /\ cur_state'= 0
                 /\ UNCHANGED << in_seq,layer_set,cur_scope,rule_nums,layer_connection_set >>

scope_changer == /\ cur_state = 5 
                 /\ cur_scope' = -1
                 /\ UNCHANGED << in_seq,layer_set,cur_state,rule_nums,layer_connection_set >>
                 

derived_def_global ==                      
                      LET 
                        temp_num == CHOOSE x \in 0..10: {x,-1} \notin layer_set
                        temp == {temp_num,-1}
                        temp_one_num == CHOOSE x \in 0..10: {x,-1} \in layer_set
                        temp_two_num == CHOOSE x \in 0..10: {x,-1} \in (layer_set\{temp})
                        temp_one == {temp_one_num,-1}
                        temp_two == {temp_two_num,-1}
                      IN
                         /\ cur_state = 1
                         /\ cur_scope = -1
                         /\ layer_set' = layer_set \union temp
                         /\ layer_connection_set' = layer_connection_set \union {<<temp_one,temp_two,temp>>}
                         /\ UNCHANGED << in_seq,cur_state,cur_scope,rule_nums >>
                       
rule_head ==     /\ cur_state = 2
                 /\ cur_scope' = drc_rule_nums
                 /\ rule_nums' = rule_nums + 1
                 /\ UNCHANGED << in_seq,layer_set,cur_state,layer_connection_set >>
                 
derived_def_rule == 
                        LET 
                        temp_num == CHOOSE x \in 0..10: {x,rule_nums} \notin layer_set
                        temp_one == CHOOSE z \in {{x,y}: x \in 0..10, y \in {-1,rule_nums}}: z \in layer_set 
                        temp_two == CHOOSE z \in {{x,y}: x \in 0..10, y \in {-1,rule_nums}}: z \in (layer_set\{temp_one}) 
                        temp == {temp_num,rule_nums}
                        IN
                            /\ cur_state = 3
                            /\ layer_set' = layer_set \union temp
                            /\ layer_connection_set' = layer_connection_set \union {<<temp_one,temp_two,temp>>}
                            /\ UNCHANGED << in_seq,cur_state,cur_scope,rule_nums >>

check_statement == 
                   LET 
                   temp_num == CHOOSE x \in 0..10: {x,rule_nums} \notin layer_set
                   temp_one == CHOOSE z \in {{x,y}: x \in 0..10, y \in {-1,rule_nums}}: z \in layer_set 
                   temp_two == CHOOSE z \in {{x,y}: x \in 0..10, y \in {-1,rule_nums}}: z \in (layer_set\{temp_one})
                   temp == {temp_num,rule_nums}
                   IN
                        /\ cur_state = 4                   
                        /\ layer_set' = layer_set \union temp
                        /\ layer_connection_set' = layer_connection_set \union {<<temp_one,temp_two,temp>>}
                        /\ UNCHANGED << in_seq,cur_state,cur_scope,rule_nums >>
                        

Next == state_changer \/ state_stabler \/ scope_changer \/ derived_def_global \/ rule_head \/ derived_def_rule \/ check_statement 

Spec == Init /\ [][Next]_vars

=============================================================================
```

I check my spec using in_layer_names <- {1,2,3,4} and in_sentence_seq <- <<1,2,3,4,5>>.Both in ordinary assignments.

And my problems are as follows:

1.TLC reports actions derived_def_global,derived_def_rule,check_statement are never enabled.

2.TLC reports error no.1 that my spec is attempting to compare integer 0 with non-integer:
{-1, 3}.

3.TLC reports error no.2 occurred when TLC was evaluating the nested
expressions in line 75 and 76.

I wonder how to rewrite my spec to make it run as what I think and solve these problems.And I hope my silly descriptions and problems won't bother you and make you angry.(

Thank you.

Comment: The code snippet does not have lines, can you point out which expression this is?

Comment: @ahelwer 
Sorry for my miss. 
I checked again with TLC in two situations:Spec == Init /\ [][Next]_vars and Spec == Init /\ Next. 
The error reports show different lines in two situations, but both situations hint that it's the bullet list parts after IN word of let-in of actions derived_def_global,derived_def_rule,check_statement causing the error. Or maybe,am I doing wrong in these three actions?

Comment: Re. problem 1: it looks like you are using `CHOOSE` when you should be using `\E`. `CHOOSE` makes an arbitrary but _deterministic_ choice. (TLC always picks the _smallest_ legal choice, but this is an implementation detail you should not rely on.) In other words, actions like `check_statement` can only fire in one possible way; they do not explore every possible value for `temp_num`. To fix this, instead of `LET var = CHOOSE x \in ... IN predicate`, use `\E var \in ...: predicate`, which (I think) is closer to what you want.

Comment: @Calvin Thank you for your hint.But I'm still confused about how to get temp,temp_one and temp_two in \E var \in ...: predicate way instead of LET var = CHOOSE x \in ... IN predicate. Can you get me a little more hint or an example?

Comment: I'm leaving a full answer so I can have code blocks; see below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my comment, you may solve some of your problems (and get closer to the system you are trying to model) by replacing `CHOOSE` with `\E`.  For example, you could rewrite `check_statement` this way:

```
check_statement ==
    \E temp_num \in 0..10:
    /\ {temp_num,rule_nums} \notin layer_set
    /\ \E temp_one \in {{x,y}: x \in 0..10, y \in {-1,rule_nums}}:
       /\ temp_one \in layer_set
       /\ \E temp_two \in ...:
          /\ ...
```

This is a good idea because in TLA+ `CHOOSE` performs an arbitrary but *deterministic* choice, and I suspect you actually want to explore every possible choice.